# My Spannable won't change color of repetitive characters

Tags: java, android, spannablestring

my Spannable won't change color of repetitive characters .For example here i have two same character of "$" dollar sign ,first one is changed to blue color but second isn't .I am putting text that i wont to change is String array. When i debug i can see all text in it how it's suppose and on proper indexes.

```
 String secondRowString = "Based on your current monthly savings of" + " $" + FormattedValue.formattedValue(model.getRetirementDdata().getCombinedCurrentMonthlySavings())
            + " at a rate of return of " + FormattedValue.formattedValue(model.getRetirementDdata().getAverageRateOfReturn()) + "% "
            + " , you are on track to have " + "$" + FormattedValue.formattedValue(model.getRetirementDdata().getHowMuchIWillHave())
            + " in total savings by " + model.getRetirementDdata().getRetirementMembersList().get(0).getName()
            + " age " + model.getRetirementDdata().getRetirementMembersList().get(0).getAgeOfRetirement();

    SpannableString strThirdRow = new SpannableString(secondRowString);
    SpannableTextUtils.setColorForPath(strThirdRow, new String[]{"$"
            , FormattedValue.formattedValue(model.getRetirementDdata().getCombinedCurrentMonthlySavings())
            , FormattedValue.formattedValue(model.getRetirementDdata().getAverageRateOfReturn()), "%", "$"
            , FormattedValue.formattedValue(model.getRetirementDdata().getHowMuchIWillHave())
            , String.valueOf(model.getRetirementDdata().getRetirementMembersList().get(0).getAgeOfRetirement())}, ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.debt_payments));
    binding.secondTV.setText(strThirdRow);
```

and my SpannableString.setColorsForPath()

```
 public static void setColorForPath(Spannable spannable, String[] paths, int color) {
    for (String path : paths) {
        int indexOfPath = spannable.toString().indexOf(path);
        if (indexOfPath == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), indexOfPath,
                indexOfPath + path.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spannable.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), indexOfPath,
                indexOfPath + path.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a logical bug in your code `indexOf` will return the first occurrence Each time . While you need to find all the occurrence of a word in String .
This can be done in multiple ways . Basically you need to solve problem `Find Indexes of all occurrences of a word in a string` .

You can use below approach .

```
public static void setColorForPath(Spannable spannable, String[] paths, int color) {
    for (String path : paths) {
        int indexOfPath = spannable.toString().indexOf(path);
        while(indexOfPath >= 0) {
            spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), indexOfPath,
                    indexOfPath + path.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            spannable.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD), indexOfPath,
                    indexOfPath + path.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            indexOfPath = spannable.toString().indexOf(path, indexOfPath+1);
        }
    }
}
```